# Compute gradient of a matrix

Tags: derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis

I have this problem where I have to compute the gradient and justify all the steps. I'm not sure how to start this task of, when calculating for a matrix. Here is the problem:
$$\nabla(\mathbf x^T\mathbf x)$$
where $\mathbf x$ is an $n$-vector.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not work with a matrix directly if it's the bottleneck,

Hint:
$$x^Tx = x_1^2 + \ldots +x_n^2$$